# Bootstrap's collapse animation not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, transition

I've been struggling with not working collapse animation. The animation is not working when I click on the toggle button. After 1 second, the whole menu appears without animation, similar to the jQuery function `show()`

Here's my code:

```html
<nav class="col-md-12 navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified main-nav">
        <li class="menu-item current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item submenu"><a href="#">Submenu</a>
          <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Any ideas why it's happening?

Comment: try to this .show("slow");

Comment: How can it help me when I do not use any jQuery to animate menu. It should be animated only with bootstrap's js. So there is something wrong.

Comment: Bootstrap requires jQuery though, are you including that?

Comment: working check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bbzhxLeb/

Comment: @JesseEarley Yes, everything is included. It seems that I have kind of conflict.  Maybe transition in the css ? Any ideas ? What else it could be ?

Comment: Probably jQuery conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code with the applicable libraries - there are several issues with the structure of the HTML according to the Bootstrap spec

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="col-md-12 navbar" role="navigation">
  <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified main-nav">
        <li class="menu-item current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item submenu"><a href="#">Submenu</a>
          <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here's a simple, working navbar taken from [Bootstrap's Docs on Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false"
        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
             aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Submenu <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   
   
  </div>
</nav>
```

I would recommend starting with the standard templates from the docs and then adapting them to your particular use case.